# Meteor: Get the post date

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having some difficulty to get the Date() to display the text with the date.

This is in my client.js:

```
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");
Template.questions.items = function(){
  return Questions.find({},{sort:{'submittedOn':-1}});
};
```

This is in clientserver.js:

```
Questions = new Meteor.Collection("questions");   
Meteor.startup(function () {
});

Meteor.methods({
addQuestion : function(questionText){
console.log('Adding Question');
var questionId = Questions.insert({
      'questionText' : questionText,
      'submittedOn': new Date(),
      'submittedBy' : Meteor.userId()
  });
return questionId;
}
});
```

How can I post the text with the date in it?

Comment: What is the `questions` template?

Answer (score 1):

You need a helper to format the date to your needs. `moment` is recommended for that. First add it:

```
mrt add moment
```

Then create a helper. See [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for formatting options.

```
UI.registerHelper('formatDate', function(date) {
  return moment(date).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
});
```

Finally use the helper in a template:

```
<template name="questions">
  {{#each items}}
    {{formatDate submittedOn}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: This is helpful. You have my gratitude!

Comment: It's usually expressed on the site by accepting the answer that was helpful :-)